# Are Azure Questions On-Topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[This azure question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370598/using-azure-dns-as-an-internal-dns-for-an-azure-vnet) was closed as off-topic

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close
>   gave this specific reason:
>
> "Questions on professional server- or networking-related
>   infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless
>   they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be
>   able to get help on Server Fault."

Stack Overflow currently has ~55k questions tagged with [azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure) but Server Fault only has ~2k questions tagged with azure.

Are azure questions now on-topic?

Was this just an old question that was closed for a reason that was valid at the time but that reason is no longer valid?

There seems to be *lots* of non-programming related questions

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[azure]+portal

Comment: It depends on the question.

Comment: `[azure]` questions that directly involve programming or programming tools may be on topic. Otherwise, most likely they aren't.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being dense, but I do not completely follow. You want to know if the rules have changed and if a similar question would be on-topic today? Because in that sense, they haven't. A similar question should be off-topic as well. Or do you want a general rule about `[azure]` questions? Because in that sense in wont be easy to get you something more specific than "it depends" and the general topicality rules.

Comment: The former. i.e. has it changed due to the volume of questions being asked.

Comment: AFAIK, there are no specific "tag rules". The rules are the same for every tag, no matter the technology. If the question involves programming and/or programming tools, it's fine. Otherwise, it's not.

Comment: If you search by non-closed questions, [there aren't that many](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bazure%5D+portal+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano), I think. Not saying that many of those aren't closable as well. I have no clue, and no horse in this race.

Comment: Azure is many, *many* different things.

Comment: It seems like there is an answer in the comments now. Who wants to post an answer and get the points? :)

Comment: You don't get points on Meta. I mean, the question and answers are voted upon, but no one receives any rep. Best you get is a badge.

Comment: *"There seems to be lots of non-programming related questions"* - *＋1*, yes. It is only going to get worse with [VSTS has been renamed to Azure DevOps - let's talk about some tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373920/608639)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends. Azure encompasses a lot of different services.

Questions about programming are always on topic. If you need help writing an Azure API call in Python, you're in the right place.

If you need help setting up a VM to host your website, then consider Server Fault.

And just because some questions got away with being asked is not a reason to ask new ones.