# Microsoft Azure support team redirecting off-topic support requests to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

While there are many possible topics / questions relating to Microsoft's [azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure) platform that would be good fits for Stack Overflow (related: [Are Azure Questions On-Topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366072/are-azure-questions-on-topic)), there's no question that not all Azure-related questions will be.

It appears that the Microsoft Azure support team on Twitter is [directing off-topic support requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58978773/protect-public-ip-on-aks-nginx-ingress-controller?noredirect=1#comment104210776_58978773) to Stack Overflow. A quick cursory glance on their [Timeline](https://twitter.com/search?q=%7Bfrom%3Aazuresupport%7D%20stack%20overflow&src=typed_query) shows both on- and off-topic discussions being directed here (including [this particularly egregious example](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport/status/1116300168205410305)).

Is there anything that can be done to have these folks briefed on our community standards? It's my understanding that in the past that these issues were raised on Meta.SO, and a Community Manager would reach out to clear things up.

Comment: "We require a forum to be created"... And MS has its own Q&A thing. Couldn't they at least field these there?

Comment: sending off topic stuff naturally complements their [porn ads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289255/839601)

Comment: It's a thing now [Is Stack Overflow becoming a support forums platform?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390976/is-stack-overflow-becoming-a-support-forums-platform)

Comment: Seen some examples of this so far, not pretty in the wild.

Comment: They are also linking us from Azure Fundamentals learning path:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-an-azure-account/6-support-options