# Microsoft lists Stack Overflow and Server Fault as support options for Azure

Tags: discussion

In the [Azure Fundamentals learning path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-an-azure-account/6-support-options), Microsoft lists Stack Overflow and Server Fault as alternative support channels.

What do you think about it? Is it a positive thing for Stack Overflow or do we risk to receive support requests? To Microsoft's credit, they phrased the suggestion in a sensible manner:

> You can review answers to questions from the development community on StackOverflow.

Related: [Microsoft Azure support team redirecting off-topic support requests to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391554/microsoft-azure-support-team-redirecting-off-topic-support-requests-to-stack-ove)

[image]

Comment: You already found a related question asking the same (at least in my point of view). Where do you see the differences in this question so the other is just related, not a dupe?

Comment: I see why you would consider it a duplicate. I find this fact interesting, and thought that maybe others would find it interesting as well. It is still Microsoft and still azure, but another website. I am new to meta, I am trying to understand what is worth to post and what is not.

Comment: The other question has no answer yet, so it can't be used as a dupe target anyway. But the question should be: is it worth to split the discussion about this subject? I have no opinion there, so I let you and other community members decide about that. When this question here gets more responses and maybe even an answer we could also think about closing the other question as a dupe of this one to centralize the discussion about Microsoft/Azure in one question.

Comment: They worded that correctly IMO. *You can review answers to questions*. That is much different then *Go ask your stuff on an SE site*.

Comment: All they need to do is spell the names of the sites correctly and they’re good to go.

Comment: Besides @rene 's observation: Microsoft people are also actively responsing on Stack Overflow. I don't know about Azure, specifically, but I do see them supporting the Office development tags.

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's funny because they *have* spelled them correctly. Once each. Then the second time it's incorrect and even inconsistent with the previous usage. Which is on the *same line*.

Comment: There are also some "broader" dupe candidates, e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253394/third-party-development-support-hosted-by-stack-overflow